# Traefik not getting SSL certificates for new domains

Tags: https, lets-encrypt, traefik, consul

I've got Traefik/Docker Swarm/Let's Encrypt/Consul set up, and it's been working fine. It managed to successfully get certificates for the domains `admin.domain.tld`, `registry.domain.tld` and `staging.domain.tld`, but now that I've tried adding containers that are serving `domain.tld` and `matomo.domain.tld` those aren't getting any certificates (browser warns of self signed certificate because it's the default Traefik certificate).

My Traefik configuration (that's being uploaded to Consul):

```
debug = false
logLevel = "DEBUG"

insecureSkipVerify = true

defaultEntryPoints = ["https", "http"]

[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.ping]
    address = ":8082"
    [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
        [entryPoints.http.redirect]
        entryPoint = "https"
    [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[traefikLog]
    filePath = '/var/log/traefik/traefik.log'
    format = 'json'
[accessLog]
    filePath = '/var/log/traefik/access.log'
    format = 'json'
    [accessLog.fields]
        defaultMode = 'keep'
        [accessLog.fields.headers]
            defaultMode = 'keep'
            [accessLog.fields.headers.names]
                "Authorization" = "drop"

[retry]

[api]
entryPoint = "traefik"
dashboard = true
debug = false

[ping]
entryPoint = "ping"

[metrics]
    [metrics.influxdb]
    address = "http://influxdb:8086"
    protocol = "http"
    pushinterval = "10s"
    database = "metrics"

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "domain.tld"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false
network = "net_web"
swarmMode = true

[acme]
email = "my@mail.tld"
storage = "traefik/acme/account"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

Possibly related, in `traefik.log` I repeatedly (as in almost once per second) get the following (but only for the `registry` subdomain). Sounds like an issue to persist the data to consul, but there are no errors indicating such an issue.

```
{"level":"debug","msg":"Looking for an existing ACME challenge for registry.domain.tld...","time":"2019-07-07T11:37:23Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"Looking for provided certificate to validate registry.domain.tld...","time":"2019-07-07T11:37:23Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"No provided certificate found for domains registry.domain.tld, get ACME certificate.","time":"2019-07-07T11:37:23Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"ACME got domain cert registry.domain.tld","time":"2019-07-07T11:37:23Z"}
```

**Update:** I managed to find this line in the log:

```
{"level":"error","msg":"Error getting ACME certificates [matomo.domain.tld] : cannot obtain certificates: acme: Error -\u003e One or more domains had a problem:\n[matomo.domain.tld] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:paramsacme:error:connection :: Fetching http://matomo.domain.tld/.well-known/acme-challenge/WJZOZ9UC1aJl9ishmL2ACKFbKoGOe_xQoSbD34v8mSk: Timeout after connect (your server may be slow or overloaded), url: \n","time":"2019-07-09T16:27:43Z"}
```

So it seems the issue is the challenge failing because of a timeout. Why the timeout though?

**Update 2:** More log entries:

```
{"level":"debug","msg":"Looking for an existing ACME challenge for staging.domain.tld...","time":"2019-07-10T19:38:34Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"Looking for provided certificate to validate staging.domain.tld...","time":"2019-07-10T19:38:34Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"No provided certificate found for domains staging.domain.tld, get ACME certificate.","time":"2019-07-10T19:38:34Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"No certificate found or generated for staging.domain.tld","time":"2019-07-10T19:38:34Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"http: TLS handshake error from 10.255.0.2:51981: remote error: tls: unknown certificate","time":"2019-07-10T19:38:34Z"}
```

But then, after a couple minutes to an hour, it works (for two domains so far).

Answer (score 0):

not sure if its a feature or a bug, but removing the following http to https redirect solved it for me:

```
 [entryPoints.http.redirect]
        entryPoint = "https"
```

Comment: That was sadly not enough in my case

Comment: This didn't help me either - I had wondered if it was incorrectly redirecting a non-TLS reply from the LE servers. However, it is worth noting that the [LE Status Page](https://letsencrypt.status.io/) is currently marked as "Partial Service Disruption".

Comment: that's not an answer. I'm still getting the same error and haven't enabled redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `acme.json` file and restart traefik container.